# update javascript date object

Tags: javascript, date, object

I am trying to update the date object through the various j/script native date object methods, but are confused why the change appears to be applied to all date objects on the page.

I had originally found a post recommending adding a method to the date prototype, but this changed all date ojects.  I then simplified and found both dates are still updating.  I would appreciate any advice on how to prevent this. What I want is a starTime and an endTime through something that looks a little like this.  (NOTE: I will eventually turn into a function).

```
time1 = new Date();
alert(time1);//returns Sat May 26 11:15:41 EDT 2012
time2=time1;
time2.setMinutes(time2.getMinutes()+10);
alert(time1); //returns Sat May 26 11:25:41 EDT 2012
alert(time2);//returns Sat May 26 11:25:41 EDT 20112
```

Question: why is date2=date1 if I only update date2.